# jQuery .click() is clicking, but it shouldn´t

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, testing

while testing my JavaScript I have the following problem:

`$('#idOfMyElement').click();`

is executed. But I want to verfiy with my test, that is is **not** executed, because it has the following CSS:

`<span style="cursor: not-allowed; pointer-events: none;" id="idOfMyElement"></span>`

I debugged it and it is sure, that when the `.click()` is executed, it has DEFINITELY the mentioned CSS-attributes. In my normal program it works (means that the click doesn´t work), but in my test the click works, even if it shouldn´t.

I have no clou, what might be the problem.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default click event using jQuery:

```
$('#idOfMyElement').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); });
```

*** UPDATE ***

Now that I know what you're trying to do, I highly recommend using javascript over CSS for this because CSS does not work the way you're trying to use it – Javascript does. Instead of using CSS attributes, use Javascript variables.

When you want the element to be clickable,

`$('#idOfMyElement').prop('disabled', false);`

When it should be unclickable,

`$('#idOfMyElement').prop('disabled', true);`

The browser takes care of the cursor without needing CSS, and click events should react appropriately. Hope that was helpful!

Comment: But with this solution the click is never executed, isn´t it? The click should only do nothing, when the mentioned css-attributes are given. Sorry for my bad english and my not existing understanding ;-)

Comment: Updated my answer to fit what you need!

Answer (score 7):

Looks like in your test you are triggering the event programmatically by using `$('#idOfMyElement').click();`; in that case it is not bound by the CSS mouse rules, and thus the click handlers will get executed.

You need to check the mouse pointer rules *before* triggering the click event in your test suite.

Comment: Ok, that means I have to be in my test more specific then in my program? In my program I don´t have an extra check for the mousepointer rules or something similar. In my program I give the element the mentioned css-attributes and then a click does nothing and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer events only respond correctly to a real pointer event. If you trigger click() function it fires in all times that you make it. Just add a condition reading if pointer events is active or replace it by a disabled attribute